# Not able to upgrade 16.04 LTS from 15.10

Tags: upgrade, 15.10

I was have an Ubuntu 15.10 image so I installed it today and but now I want to upgrade it to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, I follow these steps:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo update-manager -d
```

I got message `"Your system Up to Date"` there is no option for "upgrade"? Please help?

Comment: Why not use `update-manager -c` (the `-d` option is for upgrading to  development releases)?

Comment: BTW: no need for `sudo` before `update-manager`!

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

You need `-d` since `16.04.1` is not released yet.

Answer (score 1):

Open up the Terminal and enter the following commands, this will download and install the latest available packages:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Reboot your system to finish installing updates.

```
sudo reboot
```

Now, enter the following command to upgrade to new available version.

```
sudo update-manager -d
```

At this point, the Software Updater window should show up and it is going to search for the available new release, click on "Upgrade":

[image: software updater]

Click on "Start upgrade" for the upgrade to continue:
[image: Start upgrade]

Now, the "distribution upgrade" will download new packages. 
[image: Distribution Upgrade.]

[image: Upgrade...]

Finally restart:
[image: Restart]

When your pc boots up, you should be greeted with your brand new Ubuntu 16.4, to verify, go to **System settings > Details**, you should have something like this:
[image: System Details]

Alternatively, you can open the terminal and run:  `cat /etc/*-release` and you should see the following line: `DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Try the following

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
sudo do-release-upgrade
```